# IntelliJ and the android java docs

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Has anyone had any luck getting IntelliJ to recognize and display the android java docs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works out of the box since `Android SDK` configuration in IDEA automatically adds JavaDoc directory into `Documentation Paths`.

Make sure you've downloaded the SDK completely including the documentation using the SDK Manager. On my system they are located under `SDK_ROOT/docs/reference` and this directory is automatically configured in IDEA Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted and recreated the Android SDK and it started working. I suspected I hadn't downloaded everything when I created the the SDK the first time.

Comment: What if one want to use the online documentation? Having offline docs is kindof 1994

Comment: @Nilzor there is no problem adding URL for Android SDK documentation, IDEA will even suggest you the correct URL to add, it's [just one button click](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img913/3771/YYVAte.png).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the directory containing the documentation is in **Documentation Paths**. For this, do the following:

1. In Android Studio, open **File** -> **Project Structure**
2. Click on **SDKs** under **Platform Settings**
3. Select **Android <*version*>** in the middle panel
4. Add the following path under the **Documentation Paths** tab:

   path_to_android_sdk/docs/reference

If you have not downloaded the documentation in SDK Manager, please do so before performing this procedure.