# How to configure IntelliJ for Mac to show Java and Android documentation within the editor (offline, not online)?

Tags: java, android, macos, intellij-idea, documentation

How do I configure IntelliJ to access offline documentation (for both Java and Android if possible) without leaving my IDE? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1. My Android application is building and running fine so my installation seems to be correct. I've examined the relevant SO posts:

- [How to view JDK external documentation in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587522/how-to-view-jdk-external-documentation-in-intellij-idea?rq=1)
- [JDK documentation in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145734/jdk-documentation-in-intellij-idea-on-mac-os-x?rq=1))
- [IntelliJ and the android java docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671644/intellij-and-the-android-java-docs)

But either the paths they recommend are not on my machine (the posts are rather dated) or else too vague. Interestingly my `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` folder seems to be empty whether I use Finder or Terminal. My `Documentation paths` tab under the `File | Project Structure` menu item is empty.

I should add that I'm attempting to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keyboard command when I have a keyword highlighted.  That's what is recommended, but nothing happens.  Below are pics of my current documentation paths in the Project Structure dialog.  All done according to recommendations as far as I can see, but maybe someone can spot something.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think configuring the path to `src.zip` should be enough, IntelliJ will retrieve the Javadoc from the source files. In `Modules Settings`, in the `SDKs` panel choose your current SDK, go to the `Sourcepath` tab and make sure there's an entry for `src.zip`.

On OSX it's located under

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip
```

or

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/src.zip
```

depending on which SDK you have and how you installed it.

For the Android doc, I guess you can do the same if they provide a zip containing all the source files.

Comment: As an addendum to @Nebelmann's answer, you can find out where all your JDK installations are on MacOS X by executing the command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

Comment: I think I found the right place, but fyi there's no "Sourcepath", but a "Path" tab. 1) It would not let me specify the filename. If I tacked "src.zip" onto the end and clicked OK it wd not accept that. The dialog would not close and an error message at bottom appeared in red text: "Specified path cannot be found".  2) If I omitted "src.zip" it would accept that, but Shift+F1 still does nothing. I restarted IntelliJ afterwards fyi.

Comment: @Nebelmann -- Your answer was correct.  When I had a chance to mess with it again I realized I had src.jar files in that location rather than src.zip.  But that's a technicality. Thanks.  I often work in a remote location and needed this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Command + ; open Project Structure

on left panel select SDKs

in Sourcepath tab click +, select your src.zip

[image]